# Merge arrays with matching keys php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Ok, so someone is probably going to laugh when they read this, but I cannot get it to work. I have two arrays.

Array 1 looks like:

```
Array 
(

 [525133-004-TURQ/WHT-9] => Array
    (
        [classId] => 48
        [family] => Mens Shoes
        [onOrder] => 3.000
        [cost] => 45.000
        [sell] => 95.000
        [desc] => PAUL RODRIGUEZ 6, TURQ/WHT, 9
        [invStore] => 0.000
        [code] => 525133-004-TURQ/WHT-9
    )
)
```

Array 2 looks like:

```
Array
(

[525133-004-TURQ/WHT-9] => Array
    (
        [inv] => 0.000
    )
)
```

The result needed is:

```
Array 
(

 [525133-004-TURQ/WHT-9] => Array
    (
        [classId] => 48
        [family] => Mens Shoes
        [onOrder] => 3.000
        [cost] => 45.000
        [sell] => 95.000
        [desc] => PAUL RODRIGUEZ 6, TURQ/WHT, 9
        [invStore] => 0.000
        [code] => 525133-004-TURQ/WHT-9
        [inv] => 0.000
    )
)
```

I tried merge and it is not working. Please help!

Comment: Do you mean you tried [`array_merge_recursive `](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)?

Comment: have you tried `array_merge` ?

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: @JosephSilber how did ya embed the link in the comments?

Comment: @ryanbwork - By using [simple Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-links).

Comment: I tried array_merge. I needed array_merge_recursive. It works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

```php
$arr1 = array(
    '525133-004-TURQ/WHT-9' => array(
        'classId' => 48,
        'family' => 'Mens Shoes',
        'onOrder' => 3.000,
        'cost' => 45.000,
        'sell' => 95.000,
        'desc' => 'PAUL RODRIGUEZ 6, TURQ/WHT, 9',
        'invStore' => 0.000,
        'code' => '525133-004-TURQ/WHT-9'
    )
);

$arr2 = array(
    '525133-004-TURQ/WHT-9' => array(
        'inv' => 0.000
    )
);

$newArray = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
```

See it here in action: http://viper-7.com/jq8CgM

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $v1) {
    if (isset($arr2[$key])) {
        foreach ($arr2[$key] as $k => $v) {
            $arr1[$key][$k] = $v;
        }
    }
}
```

If i'm correct.